# How to convert a string which is an array to an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to store some array in .env files but when I access the particular value I got typeof string and I have use forEach to process my next step.
in the .env file, email is stored like this

```
EMAILS = JSON.stringify(['abc@gmail.com','abcc@gmail.com'])
```

I have used in this way also

```
EMAILS = ['abc@gmail.com','abcc@gmail.com']
```

and in this way a

```
EMAILS = "['abc@gmail.com','abcc@gmail.com']"
```

I want to make that array which is showing type of string into a normal array.

Comment: .env is not a javascript file, it is just a txt file. if you want to store multiple values, you can do the following `EMAILS = abc@gmail.com;abcc@gmail.com` and parse that string when you are reading the variable `const emails = process.env.EMAILS.split(';')`

Comment: It's not very clear. Do you mean to say while storing you're using `JSON.stringify` and you'd like to parse it back into the array while retrieving?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better not to store serialised JSON inside an `.env` file. Instead, store your "array" of items as a delimited list, for example using commas to separate the individual values. Like this:

```
# .env
EMAILS=abc@gmail.com,abcc@gmail.com
```

```
// javascript
const emails = env.EMAILS.split(",")
```

However, if you *must* store a serialised array, then you can parse it into JS by using `JSON.parse`:

```
# env
EMAILS=["abc@gmail.com","abcc@gmail.com"]
```

```
// javascript
const emails = JSON.parse(env.EMAILS)
```